# Using np.isclose() to compare np.array()

Tags: python, image, numpy

I want to use np.isclose() to compare pixel arrays of an image. Below is what I'm trying to do:

```
print(image_array.shape) # (320, 240, 4)

for i in range(0, len(image_array)):
    for j in range(0, len(image_array[i])):
        if np.isclose(image_array[i][j], [1, 0, 0, 1]):
            image_array[i][j] = [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

But I am getting the following error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

I cannot use np.all() because I want to replace all pixels that are even close enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `np.isclose`, use `np.allclose`. This will return a single boolean value for that comparison.

Comment: Would you suggest a vectorized solution if possible?

Comment: What do you mean by vectorized solution?

Comment: Without the use of for loops.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation - `isclose` "Returns a boolean array where two arrays are element-wise equal within a tolerance."

Thus, there is an array of boolean values returned which represents the is-close-ness of each value of the 4-element array. It's up to you to convert that array to a single boolean value.

You might, for instance, only care if any of the 4 match, in which case you can use `any()`; alternatively, if you care if all match, you can use `all()`.

Comment: I would like to match all but with some allowed error. If array is [1, 0.00001, 0.00001, 1] I want to consider it same as [1, 0, 0, 1]

Answer (score 0):

`image_array[i,j]` is a shape (4,) array (you can check that). `isclose` with that and `[1,0,0,1]` is a like size boolean array.  It can't be used in an `if`.  But you can apply `all` to that, or use `allclose` to test if a 'pixel' matches.

But without the double loop you can test as follows:

```
In [381]: arr = np.random.randint(0,2,(3,6,4))
In [382]: arr.shape
Out[382]: (3, 6, 4)
In [383]: np.isclose(arr,np.array([1,0,0,1]))
Out[383]: 
array([[[ True,  True, False, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False,  True],
        [ True, False, False, False]],

       [[False,  True, False, False],
        [ True,  True,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True],
        [False,  True,  True, False],
        [False, False,  True,  True]],

       [[False, False, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False, False],
        [ True, False,  True,  True],
        [False, False, False, False],
        [False, False, False,  True]]])
```

(Since I used `randint` `arr` is `int` dtype, and `==` would be just as good as `isclose`.  But the following is the same.

Applying `all` on the last dimension:

```
In [384]: np.isclose(arr,np.array([1,0,0,1])).all(axis=-1)
Out[384]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False]])
```

here one 'pixel' matches, which we can identify with:

```
In [385]: I,J = np.nonzero(_)
In [386]: I,J
Out[386]: (array([2]), array([1]))
In [387]: arr[2,1]
Out[387]: array([1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Or indexing the 2 arrays:

```
In [389]: arr[I,J]
Out[389]: array([[1, 0, 0, 1]])
```

This is a (n,4) array, where `n` is the number of matches (which could be 0).  And we can modify `arr` with that:

```
In [390]: arr[I,J]=[1,0,1,0]
```

now there's not match:

```
In [391]: np.isclose(arr,np.array([1,0,0,1])).all(axis=-1)
Out[391]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False]])
```

but there are now 3 matches to the new value:

```
In [392]: np.isclose(arr,np.array([1,0,1,0])).all(axis=-1)
Out[392]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False, False, False]])
In [393]: arr[_]          # index with the boolean mask
Out[393]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0]])
```